# How to create a match pattern for a title

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the [chrome.tabs.query](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#query) for a title.
However, if I look at the documentation, it appears that [match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) only work with URLs? Every type of pattern that I try does not work

Here is the code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'title':searchText}, function(tabArray){
    tabbr.update(tabArray);
});
```

Comment: How are you calling `.query`? `chrome.tabs.query({ title: /pattern/ }, ...)` should work, judging by the docs.

Comment: @robertklep I have updated the question with my code. I just tried typing in the slashes and still get nothing

Comment: And your extension is requesting tab-permissions, right?

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I can do everything else around tabs

Comment: Try using wildcards instead of regular expressions, that works for me (Chrome 24).

Comment: @robertklep I have already tried `*` to no avail.

Comment: I used `*string*`, that worked okay for me.

Comment: @robertklep Hrmmm, I swore I had tried the wildcard pattern before jumping to using a regex against all tabs. The * was failing because of an uncaught exception in my modified code that just used a regexp. Feel free to make your comment of using * wildcards an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The match patterns should be wildcarded strings:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'title': '*string*'}, function(tabArray){
  tabbr.update(tabArray);
});
```