# chrome tabs query title pattern ignore case

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I searched for many options but it doesn't seem that it's supported --- should I just get all the tabs and query myself?

I tried `(-i)`, it doesn't work, and there is no flag input for the query title match.

Example: I want to search all tabs with title containing "stack" (read from an input tag on html), and the query I pass into

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  title: "*stack*",               
}, function(array_of_Tabs){
  // blah
});
```

But I want to match things that are "*Stack*" as well --- in normal regex I could pass a flag like `-i` but not here. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an approximation of what you're trying to achieve? It's unclear from the question. Include some sample code.

Comment: Hey Xan I just updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Docs are not clear as to what pattern format they expect, but judging from [some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857202/how-to-create-a-match-pattern-for-a-title), it's only primitive wildcards.

It should be conceptually simpler for you to make an empty query and filter tabs yourself. I doubt it will affect performance very much for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ok I'll do that for now but I'll keep this open for a bit; it doesn't seem that hard to implement on their end.